# Load All Content When Opening The Website

Tags: angular, firebase

What I want to do is to get all of the pictures and video assets when I first get into the website. 
Show a loading prompt, in the background load everything and eliminate the slow image loading on my pages. (I really don't know why I get such slow load the pictures are no bigger than 500kb)

Comment: You should atleast post what you have tried , for us to help you out.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start, I tried searching for it but couldn't get any helpful information

Comment: Ok. Hint: Use  [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)